# Generate random number in range without specific digits

Tags: python, random

I've been googling this for some time and haven't found a solution.

I think I can do this with some lines of code but what I'm looking for is a simple (possibly one line) answer.

What I want is to generate a list of numbers between 4000 and 5000 but without certain digits: 7,8 and 9 in my case. Is there any module or function inside `random` that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do.

```
>>> num = [elem for elem in xrange(4000, 5001) if not {'7', '8', '9'}.intersection(str(elem))]
>>> choice(num)
4210
>>> choice(num)
4640
>>> choice(num)
4102
```

The comprehension works by creating a set consisting of the strings `{'7', '8', '9'}` and find the intersection of this set with the set of the digits in our number (generated from 4000 to 5000, both inclusive). If the intersection is empty, then the number does not have any of the digits specified above in which case we should include that and use the list for generating random numbers.

For example,

```
>>> {'7', '8', '9'}.intersection(str(4555))
set([])
>>> {'7', '8', '9'}.intersection(str(4765))
set(['7'])
```

Comment: that's exactly what i want, ty. Can you explain me what that `.intersection(str(elem))` does?